# Draw n random integers whose sum is equal to 100

Tags: algorithm, delphi, random, delphi-7

Pseudocode example:

```
Random function: (1 to 5, values less than 100, sum must be equal to 100 when all random numbers are added).
```

Result example:

```
Number 1 = 35
Number 2 = 15
Number 3 = 10
Number 4 = 20
Number 5 = 20
```

Comment: What have you achieved so far and where do you fail? StackOverflow is for asking questions, not delegating homework.

Comment: Have the numbers to be different? Is zero allowed? Are negative numbers allowed?

Comment: Yeah, this Q isn't well-defined. As @UweRaabe suggests, you could let it return (20, 20, 20, 20, 20) in this case; that's very easy to implement! Can some numbers be negative? If so, use 100*Random for the first n - 1 numbers, and let the last one be DesiredSum - (sum of previous). What distribution should the random numbers have?

Comment: @AmigoJack, all. Hi, I'm sorry for the unclear question. I am not infact a programmer, if anything my knowledge on the subject is very limited and I have no intention of learning/practising it any further. I should have mentioned that 0 is not allowed, and that I required integers. As well as that there are no negative numbers and that the numbers had to be different as my projected results would have demonstrated. Thank you for your answer!! Sorry for the inconvenience. I'll better communicate my requirements in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only integer numbers and Fisher-Yates shuffle:

```
program cont3;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils;
const
  SummandsCount = 5;
  WantedSum = 100;
var
  i, j, t, Cnt, WhereToInsert: integer;
  JustNaturalNumbers: array[1..WantedSum] of Integer;
  DividingPoints: array[0..SummandsCount] of Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  Cnt := 1;
  DividingPoints[0] := 0;
  DividingPoints[SummandsCount] := 100;
  for i := 1 to WantedSum - 1 do
    JustNaturalNumbers[i] := i;
  for i := WantedSum - 1 downto WantedSum - SummandsCount + 1 do begin
    j := 1 + Random(i);
    WhereToInsert := Cnt;
    while (WhereToInsert > 1) and (JustNaturalNumbers[j] < DividingPoints[WhereToInsert-1]) do begin
      Dec(WhereToInsert);
      DividingPoints[WhereToInsert + 1] := DividingPoints[WhereToInsert]
    end;
    DividingPoints[WhereToInsert] := JustNaturalNumbers[j];
    JustNaturalNumbers[j] := JustNaturalNumbers[i];
    Inc(Cnt);
  end;
  t := 0;
  for i := 1 to SummandsCount do begin
    Writeln(DividingPoints[i] - DividingPoints[i-1]);
    t := t + (DividingPoints[i] - DividingPoints[i-1]);
  end;
    Writeln('Sum = ', t);
  Readln;
end.
```

Output example:

```
22
4
7
18
49
Sum = 100
```

Comment: Linking [Is there an excuse for short variable names?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/176582)

Comment: @AmigoJack No problems

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't quite well-defined. There are many possible solutions, with different properties.

Here is the first one that sprung to my mind: create a subdivision of the interval [0, 1] into *n* parts by choosing *n* − 1 points in [0, 1] randomly. Then scale this to [0, *A*] and use the lengths of these subintervals as your *n* random numbers with sum *A*.

```
function GetRandomNumbers(ACount: Integer; const ASum: Double): TArray<Double>;
var
  Itvs: TArray<Double>;
  i: Integer;
begin

  if ACount < 1 then
    raise Exception.Create('GetRandomNumbers: Invalid parameters.');

  // Create a subdivision of [0, 1]
  SetLength(Itvs, ACount + 1);
  Itvs[0] := 0;
  for i := 1 to ACount - 1 do
    Itvs[i] := Random;
  Itvs[ACount] := 1;
  TArray.Sort<Double>(Itvs);

  SetLength(Result, ACount);
  for i := 0 to ACount - 1 do
    Result[i] := ASum * (Itvs[i + 1] - Itvs[i]);

end;
```

For example, this might give

```
16.7746451916173
7.29391833301634
22.1434036735445
3.25182809028775
50.5362047115341
```

for *n* = 5 and *A* = 100.

This uses modern Delphi techniques like generics, but the general idea should be clear enough, so you can implement it in Delphi 7 and use any sorting method you like. Also, I'll leave it as an exercise to make an integer version of `GetRandomNumbers`.

Comment: Or, in other words: if the sum is given, is it even possible that all summands are random?