# Code takes a value and divides it randomly/"unequally". How can I get it to work for real numbers/decimal values?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Please help me fix this code. I'm trying to use this code to divide large real numbers over 12 dividends which are unequal(random but still equal to the total). I got working code for Integers but this doesn't help me because I'm trying to divide monetary values which obviously have decimal values.

Would appreciate If anyone could help! :)

The idea behind the below code is as follows:
60/3 = 20, this code will randomize 3 integers to equal 60. i.e 24+19+17

`program Project2;`

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

{$R *.res}

const
  SummandsCount = 3;
  WantedSum = 60;
var
  i, j, t, Cnt, WhereToInsert: Integer;
  JustNaturalNumbers: array[1..WantedSum] of Integer; 
  DividingPoints: array[0..SummandsCount] of Integer;
//Obviously the data type changes to real didn't help :(
begin
  Randomize;
  Cnt := 1;
  DividingPoints[0] := 0;
  DividingPoints[SummandsCount] := 60;
  for i := 1 to WantedSum - 1 do
    JustNaturalNumbers[i] := i;
  for i := WantedSum - 1 downto WantedSum - SummandsCount + 1 do begin
    j := 1 + Random(i);
    WhereToInsert := Cnt;
    while (WhereToInsert > 1) and (JustNaturalNumbers[j] < DividingPoints[WhereToInsert-1]) do begin
      Dec(WhereToInsert);
      DividingPoints[WhereToInsert + 1] := DividingPoints[WhereToInsert]
    end;
    DividingPoints[WhereToInsert] := JustNaturalNumbers[j];
    JustNaturalNumbers[j] := JustNaturalNumbers[i];
    Inc(Cnt);
  end;
  t := 0;
  for i := 1 to SummandsCount do begin
    Writeln(DividingPoints[i] - DividingPoints[i-1]);
    t := t + (DividingPoints[i] - DividingPoints[i-1]);
  end;
    Writeln('Sum = ', t);
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: What you are looking are numbers that when summed give the same total? About correctness, remember that floating point math has almost always errors: most decimal numbers cannot represented exactly by binary numbers. If you have a working solution for integers, and has to handle monetary values, then transform the monetary to integers before computing and back to monetary after (For example multiply by 100 if you need two decimals. Then when you have the result, divide the found numbers by 100). BTW: You didn't told us WHY you program doesn't work for you.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209857/draw-n-random-integers-whose-sum-is-equal-to-100? (Before the Q was edited, it was not about integers specifically, and one of the As on that page is about non-integers.)

Comment: @fpiette Thank you for the reply. It was a silly question from me and I must say sorry. You are correct. I could not try the multiply by 100 because the value was too large. 600bn+ Because I knew the end value and wanted to have unequal dividends of the total value. I was able to just use 100 as a percentage marker. 12 values /100% and then with those 12 random percentages I could multiply them to the total. Sorry for not having fully provided reasoning. Thanks for your help it took me in the right direction. I appreciate it!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes you are absolutely correct, I raised that query for a whole other reason but I found that this piece of code could be handy for other uses. I was trying to rewrite it for another case. Thanks for the answer you provided previously. Especially thanks to MBo for the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to multiply the monetary values by 100 and, after processed, divide by 100 again. :)